# Altium Harness Conflict

Tags: schematics, altium, layout

Has Altium fixed the issue where Harnesses override the net names and cause a 'nets with multiple names' warning?

Has anybody found a way past without net ties? I can't afford net ties at my speeds and complexity.

I'm on ALtium 21

Comment: This is better suited to Altium support/community forum.

Comment: This question has a better chance to be answered on the Altium forum.